# How can I get a value from a database from within my MXML app?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mxml, flash-builder

I have a video phone app that works but I'm trying to now fetch some data from a database. I'm most comfortable with PHP.

I'm trying to get 1 value from a "users" table within a database called "chat" where status=1 (status being a column in the "users" table). I'm using localhost (wamp). I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this so that I could store all the data from the row into vars in my MXML app.

If i get the values with a simple PHP script, how do i get the values into my MXML app?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbh = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "select TheField from chat.users where status=1;"
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res)) == 0) {
    die("Something dun gone wrong!");
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$TheValue = $row['TheField'];
```

is about as simple as you can get. After that, it's up to you to take `$TheValue` and get it into your app.

Comment: How can I get that value into my app? I should have been more specific but thats the problem I'm having